# Can't make a function that finds the value using the key with a JSON array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I attempting to pull data from a JSON file. I cannot change the way the data is keyed or labeled in the file since it is being converted from a CSV file.

My JSON data looks like this (I am using a grep filter and then storing it in a variable but for brevity I am not showing that part unless someone needs to see it):

```
var medicare = {
    "": "",
    "80101": "NC",
    "80104": "NC",
    "80152": "24.61",
    "80154": "22.72",
    "80299": "18.83",
    "82055": "14.85",
    "82145": "9.71",
    "82542": "16.01",
    "82646": "23.91",
    "82649": "23.91",
    "83805": "24.23",
    "83840": "13.04",
    "83887": "22.26",
    "83925": "26.74",
    "83992": "20.20",
    "99080": "NC",
    "99358": "NC",
    "Carrier Type": "Medicare",
    "G0434": "12.17",
    "State": "Minnesota",
    "id": 122
}
```

I have managed to load the file using $.getJSON() and I have also managed to make a filter using $.grep() to filter arrays by State and Carrier Type. Now I need to create a function that will be able to return the value of any of the given keys.

```
function findInside( array, key ) {
    return array[key]; // <-- This is my problem.
}
```

Which I can use to return value by running:

```
console.log(findInside(medicare, "80101"))
```

I just need to be able to get the value. I don't think I need to do any loops and such. I'm still new to JavaScript and am banging my head over this one, and it should be pretty easy.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is all the relevant code code except the JSON file. I wish I wasn't using window.numbers the way I am but I being so new to this, I didn't know any other way to make it work.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // First things first, fill the state picker.
    $.each(usStates, function(i, option) {
        $('#state').append($('<option/>').attr("value", option.abbreviation).text(option.name));
    });
    // Next we need to load in the JSON Data file.
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        window.numbers = data
    });


    $("#state").change(function(){

        //Lets get the stuff in the fields.
        state = $("#state").val();
        stateName = $("#state option:selected").text();


        //Filter all through all the data.
        var workersComp = filterData("Worker's Comp", stateName);
        var commercial = filterData("Commercial", stateName);
        var medicare = filterData("Medicare", stateName);
        var medicaid = filterData("Medicaid", stateName);
        console.log(medicare);
        console.log(findInside(medicare, "80101")); // undefined



    });

})




//Functions
function filterData( i, d) {

    var r = $.grep( window.numbers, function(val, index) {
        return val.State === d;
    });
    var output = $.grep(r, function(val, index) {
            return val["Carrier Type"] ===  i;
        });
    return output
}
function findInside( array, key ) {
    return array[key];
}
```

Comment: The implementation of findInside is correct (although you are using it against a javascript object and not an array so you might want to rename the first parameter).  You might want to check the output of your grep filter.  It might be changing the structure of the medicare object.

Comment: The variable 'medicare' is returning output to the console. See: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7897357/CropperCapture%5B15%5D.png  but the findInside function is returning "undefined".

Comment: When you run this [code as is (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/XSJm4/), this works, so something else is going on.  From your linked output, the var medicare looks like an array of objects like you posted above.

Comment: Are you always guaranteed to have one each of workersComp, commercial, etc per stateName?  Also, is your filterData function just using .grep to do its work and returning the result?

Comment: @dc5 Yes. And yes. I am wondering if there is something wrong with the structure of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) method returns an array of answers.

Your logic here that filters the data is receiving an array of results back.  If you are guaranteed to have one and only one of each item, the short fix is to change:

```
    //Filter all through all the data.
    var workersComp = filterData("Worker's Comp", stateName);
    var commercial = filterData("Commercial", stateName);
    var medicare = filterData("Medicare", stateName);
    var medicaid = filterData("Medicaid", stateName);
```

To this (gets the first element in the resulting array for each type):

```
    //Filter all through all the data.
    var workersComp = filterData("Worker's Comp", stateName)[0];
    var commercial = filterData("Commercial", stateName)[0];
    var medicare = filterData("Medicare", stateName)[0];
    var medicaid = filterData("Medicaid", stateName)[0];
```

The longer term fix is to revisit your filtering logic a bit and see if you can come up with a better pattern.

For Example: If you could work your data into a form that looks something like:

```
 var states = {
     …,
     "Minnesota": {
         "Worker's Comp": {…},
         "Commercial": {…},
         "Medicare": {
             "80101": "NC",
             "80104": "NC",
             "80152": "24.61",
             ...
         },
         "Medicaid": {…}
     },
     ...
 }
```

Selecting the right value could be simplified to:

```
states[stateName]["Medicare"]["80101"]
```

Comment: @Matthew - I've added an example of a data structure that *may* better fit your needs.